# Align vertices into a straight line

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I moved one vertex in but now I have a kink in my surface.

Is there a clever way to move the second edge so the kink disappears?

[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A script.**

Thought this would be a good little exercise in edit mode bmesh scripting.

[image]

- Select two edges that share a middle vert.
- Move middle vert the least distance such that it is on the line defined by the other two.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bmesh.types import BMEdge
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_point_line
ob = bpy.context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

edges = bm.select_history[-2:]
verts = set(v for e in edges for v in e.verts)

# ensure the last two selections are both edges that share a vert
assert (
       len(verts) == 3 
       and len(edges) == 2 
       and all(isinstance(e, BMEdge) for e in edges)
       )
# All Ok, the edges 
e1, e2 = edges
# The middle vert
v =  set(e1.verts).intersection(e2.verts).pop()
# helper method to find closest point on line segment to a given point.
co, d = intersect_point_line(
        v.co,
        e1.other_vert(v).co,
        e2.other_vert(v).co
        )
v.co = co

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

other options would be to move middle vert to center (or other defined ratio) of other two, keep the ratio of lengths constant.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about a script :) That makes that may faster and less tides.

Comment: could you explain your code a bit? I get everything until verts = set(v for e in edges for v in e.verts) then don't know what it does.

Comment: OY! What's this minus 15 business? :D (Don't worry, @Phönix64, just kidding the scriptmeister...)

Answer (score 6):

**To straighten vertices to a line:**

- Set pivot to *'Active Element'*
- Select the 2 vertices at the ends, and create a *[Custom Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations)* from them. (The little '+' in the header's Transform Orientation dropdown)

  [image]
- With all 3 vertices selected, and one of the ends selected last, so active, and the new transform orientation active, hit <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, scaling to 0 in all dimensions, except 'Y', the one along the line between the end vertices.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It worked

Comment: @susu Thanks.. I'll have to watch myself... I must be getting lazy :)