# How to snap vertices to the same z and x coordinates

Tags: mesh, vertices, geometry

Please refer to the screenshot. I was making this organic shape and trying to close it and avoid using triangles at any point.

I had subdivided the border edge and connected the vertices manually. I want to align them so they form a stright line like the edge right above it. How do I do this?

[image: vertices]

Comment: See the second answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210833/align-vertices-into-a-straight-line

Comment: @JohnEason thank you. is there a menu option for this though? or is it only possible through Python

Comment: The second answer in that posting does not use a script or python which is why I specifically mentioned that one! The only change you would need to make is to select the whole line of vertices rather than just the three mentioned in that answer. There isn't a menu option for it though.

Comment: @JohnEason okay. thank you so much!